# How can I print multiple pdf pages on top of each other?

Tags: color, pdf, printing

I have two pdf pages with text and/or images. I would like to print them on top of each other, on one single page. Text and/or images have to be plotted over each other, transparent (white) regions have to remain transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First with `tikz`. This needs at least 2-3 compilations to settle down.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node at (current page.center)
       {\includegraphics[page=1,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pgfmanual.pdf}};
    \node at (current page.center)
       {\includegraphics[page=10,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pgfmanual.pdf}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[page=1,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pgfmanual.pdf}}
    \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[page=20,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pgfmanual.pdf}}
  }
  \mbox{}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The pdftk program has the `stamp` and `background` arguments that are useful for this task.  For example, I have a "draft" stamp in draft.pdf with transparent background.  I apply this stamp to a pdf as follows...

```
pdftk report.pdf stamp draft.pdf output draft_report.pdf
```